# Mapping between two files

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am new to scripting and have an requirement like below.

There is a file called jobname.txt with below contents

```
job1
job2
```

There is a file called value.txt with below contents

```
10
20
```

I need to print output like

```
update_job: job1
max_run_alarm: 10

update_job: job2
max_run_alarm: 20
```

How can I do this using shell script or awk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{printf "update_job: %s\n", $1 ; getline < "value.txt"; printf "max_run_alarm: %s\n\n", $1 }' jobname.txt
```

First `printf` command prints line from first file `jobname.txt`. Then `getline` command takes line from file `value.txt`. Then `printf` command prints that line.

see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for when and how to use `getline`.

Answer (score 7):

With `paste`+`awk`:

```
$ paste -d'\n' jobname.txt value.txt \
  |awk '{ print (NR%2?"update_job:":"max_run_alarm:", $0) }'
```

Basically with the `paste` command as its name is saying, we paste both files line by line from each but adds a single `\n`ewline character between each lines, then we re-process the previous output with `awk` and we prepend desired *"text"* for the lines which their line number is module of 2 (lines with even line numbers; for example line numbers 2, 4, 6, ...; the `NR` contains the line number of a line that *awk* is read for the processing) we prepend text  "*update_job:*" or for odd line numbers we prepend text "*max_run_alarm:*", then print the line itself `$0`.

With just `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ 
    getline val<ARGV[2]; print "update_job:", $0 ORS "max_run_alarm:", val; next
}
{ exit }' jobname.txt value.txt
```

Here we process differently, above we said NR is the line number, here you see FNR; NR and FNR has always the same value (i.e, they both contains the line number) but NR keep incrementing for all the lines of all input files, while FNR reset back to 1 as soon as the next input file was read (if any), so by saying `NR==FNR` we are ensuring that the following block of the code only runs for the first input file.

then we call "[`getline` into a Variable from a File](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fVariable_002fFile.html)" to read a single line from the second argument we passed as the input (here [`ARGV[2]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Other-Arguments.html) return `value.txt`) and save it into `val` variable; then the rest is just printing things. ORS prints a line break between each.

or maybe you prefer this one (but I don't like hard-coding fileName):

```
awk '{ 
    getline val<"value.txt"; print "update_job:", $0 ORS "max_run_alarm:", val
}' jobname.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ paste jobname.txt value.txt |
    awk '{printf "update_job: %s\nmax_run_alarm: %s\n\n", $1, $2}'
update_job: job1
max_run_alarm: 10

update_job: job2
max_run_alarm: 20
```

or all in awk:

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR { jobs[NR]=$1; next }
    { printf "update_job: %s\nmax_run_alarm: %s\n\n", jobs[FNR], $1 }
' jobname.txt value.txt
update_job: job1
max_run_alarm: 10

update_job: job2
max_run_alarm: 20
```

Both of the above use mandatory POSIX tools and so will work in any shell on every Unix box.

Answer (score 2):

In bash, the easiest way to do this is to read both files into two different arrays, then iterate from `1` to to the length of one of the arrays.

bash has a built-in command called `mapfile` to quickly read files into arrays, so I'll make use of that.

For example, using arrays `j` and `v` for jobs and values:

```bash
$ cat mapping.sh 
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -t -O 1 j < jobname.txt
mapfile -t -O 1 v < values.txt

for i in $(seq 1 "${#j[@]}") ; do
  printf "update_job: %s\n" "${j[$i]}"
  printf "max_run_alarm: %s\n\n" "${v[$i]}"
done
```

Sample output:

```
$ chmod +x ./mapping.sh
$ ./mapping.sh 
update_job: job1
max_run_alarm: 10

update_job: job2
max_run_alarm: 20
```

In `awk`:

```awk
$ cat mapping.awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

FNR==NR { # reading first file
  j[i++] = $0
  next;
}

{ # reading second file
  v[n++] = $0
}

END {
  for (i in j) {
      printf "update_job: %s\n", j[i]
      printf "max_run_alarm: %s\n\n", v[i]
  }
}
```

Output:

```
$ chmod +x ./mapping.awk
$ ./mapping.awk jobname.txt values.txt 
update_job: job1
max_run_alarm: 10

update_job: job2
max_run_alarm: 20
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 co=`awk 'END{print NR}'  jobname.txt`

for ((i=1;i<=$co;i++)); do awk -v i="$i" 'NR==i{print "update_job: "$1}' jobname.txt; awk -v i="$i" 'NR==i{print "max_run_alarm: "$1}' value.txt;echo -e "\n"; done
```

output

```
update_job: job1
max_run_alarm: 10


update_job: job2
max_run_alarm: 20
```

Answer (score 1):

In bash... utilizing an **extra file descriptor**, both files can be simultaneously iterated through in a while loop like so:

```bsh
while read -r j
do
    read -r v <&4
    printf "update_job: %s\nmax_run_alarm: %s\n\n" "$j" "$v"
done <"jobname.txt" 4<"value.txt"
```

Giving this end result:

```
update_job: job1
max_run_alarm: 10

update_job: job2
max_run_alarm: 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **GNU sed** we can do it by running two seds in parallel and pasting the output of one into the pattern space of the other via the `R` command

```
$ < values.txt \
  sed -e 's/^/max_run_alarm: /' \
| sed -e '
    s/^/\nupdate_job: /
    1s/.//; R/dev/stdin
' keys.txt
```

---

One more way is using **python3** and zip the iterators of the two file handles:

```
$ python3 -c 'import sys
keys,values = sys.argv[1:]
p,q = "update_job:","max_run_alarm:"
with open(keys) as k, open(values) as v:
  for a,b in zip(k,v):
    print(p,a+q,b,sep=" ")
' keys.txt values.txt
```

---

Using **perl** we can place one file in stdin' other on the command line:

```
$ perl -ne '
  print for(
    "update_job: $_",
    "max_run_alarm: ".<STDIN>."\n");
' keys.txt < values.txt
```

---

**Output:**

```
update_job: job1
max_run_alarm: 10

update_job: job2
max_run_alarm: 20
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ed` is available/acceptable.

The script `script.ed`

```
$t.
s/.\{1,\}//
1r value.txt
$m$-3
$-1m$
g/./s/^\(job[0-9]\{1,\}\)$/update_job: \1/\
s/^\([0-9]\{1,\}\)$/max_run_alarm: \1/
,p
Q
```

---

Then run

```
ed -s jobname.txt < script.ed
```

---

- Change the `Q` to `w` if you're satisfied with the output and *in-place* editing will occur.
- Remove the `,p` to silence the output.