# How to insert subsequent lines from input file at the end of each line of another file?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have two files with log output. I need to join them the way I described below

First file

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

Second File

```
Need to be placed at the end of Line 1
Need to be placed at the end of Line 2
Need to be placed at the end of Line 3
```

Expected result:

```
Line 1 Need to be placed at the end of Line 1
Line 2 Need to be placed at the end of Line 2
Line 3 Need to be placed at the end of Line 3
```

I know how append text/input file using sed but in case of file it will insert all contents of a file so it's not what I am looking for. Any help appreciated:)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print two files in two columns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392655/print-two-files-in-two-columns)

Comment: @αғsнιη Doesn't seem to be an exact dupe as the user in the other question is aware of `paste` but tries to overcome a limitation in it.

Comment: what if your inputs would looks like the ones mentioned in this answer? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/392658/72456. do you mind lines of each files interference within each other position?

Comment: @Kusalananda emm, does the opinion of the asker there matter?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the files should be "joined together" line by line, use `paste`.

The `paste` utility takes input from one or several files, and produces output consisting of the files "pasted side by side".  The `paste` utility creates columns of the files listed on its command line.

```bsh
paste first_file second_file
```

To use a space as the delimiter between the files (instead of the default tab character), use `paste` with its `-d` option:

```bsh
paste -d ' ' first_file second_file
```

See also the manual for `paste` on your system.

In a sense, `paste` does the opposite of `cut`, which extracts fields/columns.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

`awk 'NR==FNR { arr[NR]=$0; next}{ printf "%s %s\n", arr[FNR], $0 }' first_file second_file`

`NR==FNR{ arr[NR]=$0` This will create an array `arr` indexed on lines(record numbers) for first file only. This is because FNR is set to zero when awk starts reading second file whereas NR is total records read so far from all files, i.e. NR is not set to zero when new file is started for reading.

The `next` statement tells awk to stop processing current record(read line) and go to next record. This means no further commands will be executed for current line. Therefore, after creating array `arr`, the `printf` statement is not executed for first file.

Next `printf` prints `arr` and all records from second file.

I did nothing but *slightly* changed command taken from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/649407/469418).